# Is it possible to make a vlookup on a table and after that update the value using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm storing some references in a table that I want to retrieve before updating the value.

I'm trying this:

```
Private Function getTable(sheetName As String, tableName As String) As Excel.ListObject
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets(sheetName)

    Set getTable = ws.ListObjects(tableName)
End Function

Private Function getMaxRef(tableName As String) As Integer
    Dim lo As Excel.ListObject
    Set lo = getTable("Aux", "references")

    Dim result As Variant

    result = Application.VLookup(tableName, Range(lo), 2, False)

    getMaxRef = result
    'After this I want to change the value found by vLookup


End Function
```

I don't think vlookup is the best way to achieve this, but at least is easier to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Before we start answering, one important question to ask is ... are you intending `getMaxRef` to be used as a UDF?  If so, the answer is a simple "no". But if you aren't trying to create a UDF then we can start telling you how to use `Match` and `Index`, etc.

Comment: @YowE3K No getMaxRef will only be used on VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that what you want to do is something like:

```
Private Function getMaxRef(tableName As String) As Integer
    Dim lo As Excel.ListObject
    Set lo = getTable("Aux", "references")

    Dim r As Variant

    r = Application.Match(tableName, lo.DataBodyRange.Columns(1), 0)

    If IsError(r) Then
        MsgBox "Record not found"
        getMaxRef = -1
    Else
        getMaxRef = lo.DataBodyRange.Cells(r, 2)
        'After this I want to change the value found by vLookup
        lo.DataBodyRange.Cells(r, 2) = lo.DataBodyRange.Cells(r, 2) + 1
    End If
End Function
```